# Rotate buttons on orientation change like in native camera app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

Does anyone know how could I make buttons rotate **in place** on rotation change like they rotate in the native iPhone app?

I am developing for iOS 6 and higher, so I am working with methods `shouldAutorotate` etc.

I tried to return `YES` and then change frame, but that made the icons "move", instead of rotate in place. I thought of returning `NO` and make custom `UIView` animation, but I am not sure how to obtain data about current and upcoming orientation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rotate the button with CGAffineTransformation instead of just changing the frame.

```
self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(someRadians);
```

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/61080-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-changes-height-and-width-of-image.html